# Selecting first UL using CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to select first UL using CSS in the DIV, this is the HTML that I use

```
<div class="block">
    <h2>External</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="indicator success"></span>1</li>
        <li><span class="indicator success"></span>2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="indicator success"></span>1</li>
        <li><span class="indicator success"></span>2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `first-of-type`

```
ul:first-of-type {
    /* css rules */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/as511r4m/)**

```css
ul:first-of-type {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h2>External</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="indicator success"></span>1</li>
    <li><span class="indicator success"></span>2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="indicator success"></span>1</li>
    <li><span class="indicator success"></span>2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That kind of works, but when I add a class:
.block ul:first-of-type {
    /* css rules */
} it fails

Comment: @demo yeah I made a mistake... thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

There is **two ways** to achieve it:

1. `ul:first-of-type`
2. `ul:nth-child(2)`

`

Comment: `first-child` won't work because, in the example, it is not actually the first child...

Answer (score 2):

Use :first-child

```
ul:first-child {
    /* css rules */
}
```

Comment: That kind of works, but when I add a class:
.block ul:first-of-type {
    /* css rules */
} it fails

Comment: This selects EVERY first-child of that type

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
ul:nth-of-type(1) {

/* CSS Rules */

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are right, but you should preceed them with `.block` parent selector to select only inside the wanted div:

```css
.block ul:first-of-type {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h2>External</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="indicator success"></span>1</li>
    <li><span class="indicator success"></span>2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="indicator success"></span>1</li>
    <li><span class="indicator success"></span>2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```